# Get Stripe to charge existing card on subscription change

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I'm offering my customers monthly subscriptions. When they sign up to a paid subscription plan for the first time they are shown a PaymentElement to capture their credit card details. Once this is complete the customer has a new payment method stored on Stripe. This works fine.

However, when the customer wants to upgrade to a higher subscription plan, Stripe creates a prorated payment on the customer, but for some reason, doesn't actually charge the customer's existing payment method. The payment on Stripe is sitting at `Incomplete` with the message `The customer hasn't attempted to pay this invoice yet`.

My question is, why doesn't Stripe just charge the customer using the already stored payment method? Why is it waiting for the customer to pay?

This is how I'm initiating the upgrade (This is also the same code I use to move to the customer to a paid subscription, capturing their card details):

```
var service = new SubscriptionService();
var subscription = service.Get(subscriptionId);

var paymentSettings = new SubscriptionPaymentSettingsOptions
{
    SaveDefaultPaymentMethod = "on_subscription"
};

var options = new SubscriptionUpdateOptions
{
    CancelAtPeriodEnd = false,
    ProrationBehavior = "always_invoice",
    Items = new List<SubscriptionItemOptions>
    {
        new SubscriptionItemOptions
        {
            Id = subscription.Items.Data[0].Id,
            Price = planPriceCombo.Item2
        }
    },
    PaymentSettings = paymentSettings,
    PaymentBehavior = "default_incomplete"
};

options.AddExpand("latest_invoice.payment_intent");

var updatedSubscription = service.Update(subscriptionId, options);
```

Have I configured this subscription update incorrectly? How would I go about getting Stripe to just automatically charge the payment method already attached to the customer without waiting?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is passing `PaymentBehavior = "default_incomplete"` which indicates to Stripe that you don't want them to attempt to pay the Invoice by confirming its underlying PaymentIntent. If you look at `updatedSubscription.LatestInvoice.PaymentIntent.Status` it likely is in `requires_confirmation` to reflect this. In that case, you would use the PaymentIntent's `ClientSecret` value to confirm the PaymentIntent client-side, for example in case 3DS is needed.

Since you want Stripe to automatically attempt payment of the Invoice on creation, what you need to do is switch to `PaymentBehavior = "allow_incomplete"` instead. This means Stripe will attempt a payment synchronously but if it fails or requires a customer action (such as doing 3DS) it won't error and still go through with the update. This will then let you attempt to confirm the PaymentIntent client-side if needed.

Comment: Okay cool that makes sense. I don't really want the update to go through if something goes wrong with the payment. How would I go about confirming the payment intent client side? I tried calling the confirmPayment method, but that returns an error saying it needs a payment element, which, if I'm using an existing payment method, shouldn't be shown.